# Android android.permission.SEND_SMS does not work properly

Tags: android, telephonymanager, smsmanager

I am trying to create an app for my personal use. I want to send message to one number when by bettery percentage goes below 5%.

I am getting the battery level and trying to send SMS using SmsManager like below.

```
private void getBatteryPercentage() {
    BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            int currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            int level = -1;
            if (currentLevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                level = (currentLevel * 100) / scale;
            }
            batteryPercent.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
            //if(level<=5 && notSent){
            //    notSent=false;
            //   SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
            //  Log.d("Sending message to", "9999999999");
            //   smsManager.sendTextMessage("9999999999",null,"Battery percent: "+level+"%",null,null);
            // }
        }
    };
    IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
}
```

The problem is when I comment the Message part, it works fine and shows the battery percentage. But if i un-comment that part and try to send message i get the following error.

```
      09-02 17:03:06.795  12849-12849/com.example.karthik.lowbattery E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.example.karthik.lowbattery, PID: 12849
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) } in com.example.karthik.lowbattery.MyActivity$1@4517e460



      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10268 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
      at android.os.Parcel.readException
```

But actually i have permission to send SMS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.karthik.lowbattery" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="andriod.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a small error in the `<uses permission......>`. The spelling of android is incorrect.

It should be as below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: For anyone else .. its case-sensitive ..so <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/> is the same as <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS"/>